# Unable to connect to Teradata through VBA macro with mechanism as LDAP

Tags: vba, excel, teradata

Tried with the following code to connect to Teradata and it is working fine

```
  Worksheets("BO").range("A:C").Clearcontents
  conn.Open "Driver={Teradata};" & _
  "DBCName=" & TDServer & ";" & _
  "Database=" & TDDb & ";" & _
  "Uid=" & TDUname & ";" & _
  "Pwd=" & TDPword & ""
```

Unable to connect to "LDAP" mechanism and it is throwing Userid/password is invalid even after including the "Authentication" as LDAP in the above code

Comment: Try  "User ID=" instead of "Uid=!" and " Password=" instead of "Pwd=". You could also add "; Persist Security Info=True; Session Mode=ANSI;" to your string.

Comment: I tried the same, but still not able to connect to LDAP Mechanism..

Comment: what are the values of the variables when it reaches that point? Do you have `Option Explicit` to make sure there are no typos?

Comment: I have used the below code "conn.Open "Driver={Teradata};" & _
 "Persist Security Info=True;Session Mode=ANSI;" & _
 "DBCName=" & TDServer & ";" & _
 "Database=" & TDDb & ";" & _
  "UserID=" & TDUname & ";" & _
  "Password=" & TDPword & ""

Comment: @SeanC : I tried but still no luck

Comment: Can you login to Teradata with bteq or SQL assistant with those credentials?

Comment: @ MarcinSzaleniec : Yes , i am able to login manually but not from the code

Comment: that looks like ODBC (i.e. databases) not LDAP (a directory service)

Comment: Have you tried to specify `LOGMECH=LDAP` as a parameter in the connection string? The default mechanism is often `TD2` or database authentication.

Comment: @RobPaller : yes tried with Authentication=LDAP in the connection string , but still not working

Comment: What does the DBC.LogOnOffV View show for the authentication method of the failed login? I think you should find the LDAP failed authentication attempt in the /var/log/messages file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried one more technique apart from the solution provided above , assign a variable for the authentication mechanism and by using if else loop we can run the same

```
 If (LDAPString = "LDAP") Then

 Conn.Open "Driver={Teradata};" & _
"DBCName=" & TDServer & ";" & _
"Database=" & TDDb & ";" & _
"Uid=" & TDUname & ";" & _
"Pwd=" & TDPword & ";" & _
"Authentication=LDAP"

 Else

 Conn.Open "Driver={Teradata};" & _
"DBCName=" & TDServer & ";" & _
"Database=" & TDDb & ";" & _
"Uid=" & TDUname & ";" & _
"Pwd=" & TDPword & ""

End If
```

Answer (score 2):

It's necessary when to specify your authentication mechanism when connecting through a non-default auth mech. You do that in your ODBC connection string using the `Authentication` setting.

In your case:

```
conn.Open "Driver={Teradata};" & _
  "DBCName=" & TDServer & ";" & _
  "Database=" & TDDb & ";" & _
  "Uid=" & TDUname & ";" & _
  "Pwd=" & TDPword & ";" & _
  "Authentication=LDAP"
```

A few other very useful settings to consider in your connection string:

`SessionMode`. This should default to "Teradata", but I like to specify just in case since you have to be more explicit about your SQL if you find yourself in `ANSI` mode.

```
  "SessionMode=Teradata"
```

`CharSet` which defaults to `ASCII` which may be fine for you needs, but if you have any data that is Unicode, then you will need to specify a Unicode character set in your connection string to avoid the Unicode characters being dumbed down to ASCII (Question marks and empty boxes are common replacements)

```
  "CharSet=UTF8"
```

As an example, here is my connection function that I've been using for years to handle LDAP connections:

```
Public adoConn as ADODB.Connection
Private username as string
Private password as string

<other supporting functions here like getUsername and getPassword>

Function openConnection() As Boolean
    Dim ServerName As String, DatabaseName As String
    Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
startOver:
    If m_db.username = "" Or m_db.password = "" Then
        getUsername
        getPassword
    End If

    'ldap
    adoConn.Open "SessionMode=Teradata;Driver=Teradata;Authentication=LDAP;DBCName=mydb.somewhere.com;Database=mydb;CharSet=UTF8;Uid=" & username & ";Pwd=" & password        

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
     If Err.Number = -2147217843 Then
        yesno = MsgBox("Your username or password was incorrect." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Try Again?", vbYesNo)
        If yesno = vbYes Then
            m_db.password = ""
            GoTo startOver
        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print Err.Description, Err.Number        
End Function
```

---

Updating with a version that can work using a paramter to toggle ldap functionality:

```
Public adoConn as ADODB.Connection
Private username as string
Private password as string

<other supporting functions here like getUsername and getPassword>

Function openConnection(ldap as boolean) As Boolean
    Dim ServerName As String
    Dim DatabaseName As String
    Dim strConnection as string
    Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
startOver:
    If m_db.username = "" Or m_db.password = "" Then
        getUsername
        getPassword
    End If

    'ldap        
    If ldap Then 
        strConnection = "SessionMode=Teradata;Driver=Teradata;Authentication=LDAP;DBCName=mydb.somewhere.com;Database=mydb;CharSet=UTF8;Uid=" & username & ";Pwd=" & password  
    Else 'not ldap      
         strConnection = "SessionMode=Teradata;Driver=Teradata;DBCName=mydb.somewhere.com;Database=mydb;CharSet=UTF8;Uid=" & username & ";Pwd=" & password  
    End If

    'open the connection
    adoConn.Open strConnection

    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
     If Err.Number = -2147217843 Then
        yesno = MsgBox("Your username or password was incorrect." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Try Again?", vbYesNo)
        If yesno = vbYes Then
            m_db.password = ""
            GoTo startOver
        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print Err.Description, Err.Number        
End Function
```

You can now call this like:

```
Set connTeradataProd = openConnection(True) 'for ldap
Set connTeradataStage = openConnection(False) 'for default auth
```

Comment: Would have figured LOGMECH over AUTHENTICATION. Good snippet of code to have tucked away.

Comment: @RobPaller It may be a difference in ODBC driver versions. I could swear I remember using LOGMECH a long time ago (or perhaps it was in OLEDB connection strings...) I can't remember

Comment: @JNevill : I use the same code to connect to stage and prod earlier, now Prod credentials has LDAP mechanism so unable to connect the same and the above piece of code worked perfectly to connect to Production now .. If i have to connect to stage again i have to remove Auth mechanism and run it  .. Is there any way to work with the same piece of code to connect to stage (without LDAP ) and Prod ( With LDAP ) with the same template

Comment: Sure thing. This is just a function and functions can take parameters. Your parameter could be a boolean (true/false) for production (as one possible solution). I will update the answer with a version of the function that will work like that and you can tweak it however you wish.

Comment: No. I'm not available to debug my way through your workbook's errors and all that comes with that. What error are you getting? If it's reasonably complex enough, it may warrant a new question out here to SO so other folks can jump in and offer support.